# How to use LsaLookupSids2 correctly?

Tags: c, winapi, msys2, msvcrt

I'm trying to retrieve the information from a share using the C Windows API. For compilation I'm using the MINGW64 flavor of MSYS2 (https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/). But I'm having problems when I try to convert the SIDs in the security descriptor to plain text names. This is a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <lm.h>
#include <ntstatus.h>
#include <ntsecapi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        NET_API_STATUS res1;
        NTSTATUS res2;

        // Get info from share

        SHARE_INFO_502 *info;
        res1 = NetShareGetInfo(L"domain.tld", L"test", 502, (LPBYTE *)&info);
        if (res1 != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "NetShareGetInfo failed with error %d\n",
                         res1);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Validate security descriptor

        SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR *sd = info->shi502_security_descriptor;

        if (IsValidSecurityDescriptor(sd) == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Security descriptor is not valid\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Open policy handle

        LSA_HANDLE polHandle;
        LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES polAttrs;
        memset(&polAttrs, '\0', sizeof(polAttrs)); // must be zero according to docs

        res2 = LsaOpenPolicy(NULL, &polAttrs, POLICY_EXECUTE, &polHandle);
        if (res2 != STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "LsaOpenPolicy failed with error %d (converted from %lX)\n",
                        LsaNtStatusToWinError(res2), res2);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Translate owner SID

        LSA_TRANSLATED_NAME *names;
        LSA_REFERENCED_DOMAIN_LIST *domains;

        res2 = LsaLookupSids2(polHandle, 0, 1, &sd->Owner, &domains, &names);
        if (res2 != STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "LsaLookupSids2 failed with error %d (converted from %lX)\n",
                        LsaNtStatusToWinError(res2), res2);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // do something here with names and domains

        LsaFreeMemory(names);
        LsaFreeMemory(domains);

        return 0;
}
```

I then compile it and execute it:

```
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\c-tests\sdproblem>main.exe
LsaLookupSids2 failed with error 87 (converted from C000000D)
```

Error 87 means "The parameter is incorrect". It seems I'm not passing the arguments correctly to the `LsaLookupSids2` function. But I'm not able to see what I'm doing wrong. I've tried passing some flags in the second argument instead of `0` to no avail. I've also tried to use `LsaLookupSids` (and remove the second argument) but still no luck. The share exists and the permissions can be retrieved by `icacls`:

```
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\c-tests\sdproblem>icacls \\domain.tld\test
\\domain.tld\test Everyone:(OI)(CI)(F)
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: `sd->Owner == 0` in your case. also if you open `LsaOpenPolicy` - need call `LsaClose(polHandle);` and so on

Comment: Thanks, you're totally right. But quick follow up question: I just checked that `sd->Group != 0`. If I replace `sd->Owner` with `sd->Group` in the above code I get a `Segmentation fault` exception. Do you know why?

Comment: windows have no *Segmentation fault* exception. you not check are *sd* is absolute or self relative. you assume that it is absolute form. but this is false. you need use `GetSecurityDescriptorGroup` for instance .. and and alll too many errors in code

Comment: i already not say that group almost not have any sense

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old but I just want to post what I ended up doing to solve it. There were mainly two issues in the code that I had to overcome.

1. `NetShareGetInfo` returns the security descriptor in self-relative form. But to manipulate a security descriptor it must be in absolute form. I used the [`MakeAbsoluteSD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-makeabsolutesd) function to convert the returned SD into absolute form.
2. Given an SID the best way to look up the name associated to it is to use the [`LookupAccountSidW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountsidw) function (instead of the `LsaLookupSids2` function that I tried to use).